# Conditional probability based on gender problems

Tags: probability

Q:-Suppose that the probability that both twins are boys is p and that both are girls is q ; suppose also that when the twins are of different sexes the probability of the first born being a  girl is 0.5. If the first born of twins is a girl, what is the probability that second is also a girl?

Comment: Probably the reason someone voted to close this is that it is phrased in language suitable for assigning homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{cclcccl}
& & & \text{two boys} \\
& & \nearrow \\
& \nearrow \\
& \rightarrow & \rightarrow & \text{one of each} & \rightarrow & \text{girl first} & \text{probability} = (1-p-q)\cdot\dfrac 1 2 \\
& \searrow & & & \searrow \\
& & \searrow & & & \text{boy first} \\
& & & \text{two girls} \\
& & & & \searrow \\
& & & & & \text{girl first} & \text{probability} = q \\ \\
\hline \\
\end{array}
$$
The probability that the first is a girl is thus $\Big((1-p-q)\cdot \frac 1 2 \Big) + \Big( q \Big).$ The probability that both are girls is $q.$

Therefore the conditional probability that both are girls given that the first is a girl is $$ \frac q {(1 - p -q) \cdot \frac 1 2 + q}. $$ This simplifies to $$ \frac{2q}{1-p+q}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the event that the first child is a girl and $B$ be the event that the second child is a girl. Then we have that:

$$P(B|A) = \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)} = \frac{q}{q + \frac 12(1-p-q)}$$

Comment: @nicola You're right. It all started with the bad notation. I guess that's what late hours do to you.